# JAXB Marshalling - Not getting expected xml hierarchical structure while marshalling sub model

Tags: inheritance, jaxb, marshalling

I have a base abstract class named ***Contact*** and two sub classes named ***Phone*** and ***Address*** which extends the base class ***Contact***.

Have  another model named  ***Customer*** which contains properties of type ***Contact***

**Contact.java**

```
package test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;

@XmlSeeAlso({Address.class, Phone.class})
public abstract class Contact {

}
```

**Phone.java**

```
package test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
@XmlRootElement
public class Phone extends Contact {

private String number;

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}
}
```

**Address.java**

```
package test;

public class Address extends Contact{

private String name;
private String city;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}   
}
```

**Customer.java**

```
package test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

@XmlElement(name="contact")
private Contact contact1;

    public Contact getContact1() {
        return contact1;
    }

    public void setContact1(Contact contact) {
        this.contact1 = contact;
    }

@XmlElement(name="contact")
private Contact contact;

    public Contact getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(Contact contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

}
```

The scenario is, when I try to marshal the **Customer** model I am getting the expected xml hierarchy as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer>
    <contact xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="phone">
        <number>12345</number>
    </contact>
    <contact xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="address">
        <city>New York</city>
    </contact>
</customer>
```

JAXB able to find out the type of the Customer model properties (contact and contact1 as Address and Phone) and the same has been generated as xml.

But When I try to marshal the model **Phone** the generated output does not considered the parent model **Contact**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<phone>
    <number>12345</number>
</phone>
```

I was expecting that the output xml will have the Contact model element also denoted since its the parent element.

This is the code I used for doing marshalling

```
package test;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Customer customer = new Customer();
        Address address1 = new Address();
        address1.setCity("New York");
        customer.setContact(address1);

        Phone p = new Phone();
        p.setNumber("12345");

        customer.setContact1(p);

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class, Contact.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);       
        marshaller.marshal(p, System.out);       

    }

}
```

Please someone let me understand how can I get the expected xml output.